# HTTP Server - Audio File Request Results In Live Broadcasting

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, server, chromecast

So my goal is to Chromecast local media using the Xamarin.iOS binding for the Cast SDK. I learned that in order to do this, a small server would have to be set up to serve the audio files. Thus Googling around, I was able to put this together:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace HTTPServer
{
    class HTTPServer
    {
        private Thread _serverThread;
        private HttpListener _serverListener;
        private string _rootDirectory;

        public HTTPServer(string folderPath)
        {
            this._rootDirectory = folderPath;
            this.Start();
        }

        private void Start()
        {
            _serverThread = new Thread(this.Listen);
            _serverThread.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server Started...");
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _serverThread.Abort();
            _serverListener.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Server Stopped...");
        }

        private void Listen()
        {
            _serverListener = new HttpListener();
            _serverListener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:8080/");
            _serverListener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpListenerContext serverContext = _serverListener.GetContext();
                    Process(serverContext);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Exception 1: \n" + ex);
                }
            }
        }

        private void Process(HttpListenerContext serverContext)
        {
            string fileName = serverContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Substring(1);
            Console.WriteLine(fileName);

            string filePath = Path.Combine(_rootDirectory, fileName);

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                try
                {
                    FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

                    // Chunked
                    //serverContext.Response.SendChunked = true;

                    // Status
                    serverContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;

                    // Date
                    serverContext.Response.AddHeader("Date", DateTime.Now.ToString("r"));

                    // Content-Type
                    serverContext.Response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";

                    // Content-Length
                    //serverContext.Response.ContentLength64 = inputStream.Length;
                    serverContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", inputStream.Length.ToString());

                    // Last Modified
                    //serverContext.Response.AddHeader("Last-Modified", System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath).ToString("r"));

                    // Connection
                    serverContext.Response.KeepAlive = false;

                    // Content-Disposition
                    //serverContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");

                    // Content-Range
                    serverContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Range", $"bytes 0-{inputStream.Length - 1}/{inputStream.Length}");

                    // Accept-Ranges
                    //serverContext.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");

                    inputStream.CopyTo(serverContext.Response.OutputStream);
                    inputStream.Close();

                    serverContext.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    serverContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    Debug.WriteLine("Exception 2: \n" + ex);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                serverContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            }

            serverContext.Response.OutputStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I go to let's say http://127.0.0.1:8080/Sample.mp3 in my browser, it comes up as a Live Stream. I'm trying to get it to serve the audio file as is, including the duration such as if you were to visit http://www.montemagno.com/sample.mp3. I checked the headers and I have tried a lot of different combinations.

If I use the Montemagno link directly to Chromecast, it seems to work.

I'd appreciate any input or help! Been scratching my head with this for a while now.

EDIT 1:
Just for clarification, I ran the Montemagno link under a online tool and got the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK => 
Date => Fri, 11 Aug 2017 15:27:17 GMT
Server => Apache
Last-Modified => Mon, 04 Nov 2013 16:53:47 GMT
ETag => "7a20ac-4ea5cc2740d24"
Accept-Ranges => bytes
Content-Length => 8003756
Cache-Control => max-age=2592000
Expires => Sun, 10 Sep 2017 15:27:17 GMT
Connection => close
Content-Type => audio/mpeg
```

EDIT 2:
So I downloaded Postman to check the responses I was getting. When I send a GET request to the Montemagno file, I get a response back. However when I send a GET request to the local server, it says `No Response`.

So in my code it outputs every time a file is requested. When I request through Postman, I get 1 request and then the `No Response`. However when I load the link through Safari, I get 3 requests to the file before it starts streaming the audio. And in the exception, it seems to throw a `Cannot be changed after headers are sent` message back at me.

Not sure if that sheds any input on what I'm doing wrong. Alternatively, is there any other way I could set up a local server to serve audio files in C#? I just need it so I can serve the media to the Chromecast via the Cast SDK.

Comment: From the top of my head: Use `Content-Length:` instead of content-range with a key of the total number of bytes in your response (mp3), add `Accept-Ranges:` key with a string value of `bytes` and a `Connection:` key a value of `close`

Comment: @SushiHangover I tried using those, but still no dice. Shows up as Live Broadcasting still: http://imgur.com/a/7QyWr